# Why can't I swap the token using swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens?

Tags: blockchain, web3.py, pancakeswap

i use the function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens web3 py for swap MATIC to WBNB, but always get errors what is wrong with my code?

```
input_token_address = web3.toChecksumAddress('0xcc42724c6683b7e57334c4e856f4c9965ed682bd')
output_token_address = web3.toChecksumAddress('0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c')

swap_path = [input_token_address, output_token_address]
input_quantity = 1
input_quantity_wei = (Web3.toWei(input_quantity, 'ether'))
max_input = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(input_quantity_wei, swap_path).call()
max_input = int(max_input[1])
tx = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(input_quantity_wei, max_input, swap_path, account_address, (int(time.time()) + 10000)).buildTransaction({
'from': account_address,
'value': input_quantity_wei,
'gasPrice': Web3.toWei(current_gas, 'gwei'),
'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address),
})
```